# Apache mod_rewrite for SEO urls, but rewrite to 404 if file doesn't exist

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm unable to find the answer for this, so please let me know if it's been resolved before.

I'm using mod_rewrite to do "pretty" URLs, but if you request a file that doesn't exist (like, a typo) it will redirect and add .php a bunch of times and then fail. The code I have below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://inquisito.rs/$1/ [R=301,l]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

So if you go to http://inquisito.rs/aion/ it will show you the aion page, but if you go to, lets say, inquisito.rs/aio/ on accident, it gives this

http://inquisito.rs/aio.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php/

Thanks in advance, I can't tell you how many times I've used information from here to resolve issues at work and at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example you've given, this is how the rules are applied:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f        # /aio/ is not a file, so this matched
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$         # This DOES NOT match, because you have a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://inquisito.rs/$1/ [R=301,L]  # This rule doesn't run, because the condition above wasn't met

# This rule is separate from the RewriteConds above
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]            # This does match because of the lack of RewriteConds and because you have a trailing slash
```

Try this (untested) set of rules instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f      # Make sure no matching file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$         # Don't match requests that already end .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$       # Check for missing trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://inquisito.rs/$1/ [R=301,L]  # Redirect with trailing slash

# Separate rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$       # Don't match requests that already end .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]          # Internal redirect to matching PHP file
```

**It's important to note that all matching RewriteRules cause a new request to be processed by htaccess again.**

Comment: That didn't appear to work, though the explainations are useful. I'll play around with it a bit to see if I can't get it fixed

Comment: I updated the answer a couple of times, it may still not be quite right, but worth checking you're using the latest update.

Comment: This most recent revision seems to work, but it still errors if you attempt to access something that isn't there, giving the same redirect loop. I think there's a way to test if the file exists, and then strip .php from it, and then if the file doesn't exist, then rewrite to a 404, no? Should be something similar to what's there, though I'm not too clear how it would work

Comment: I just used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to help, and realised that the first set of conditions were being met after the internal redirect was happening (because the request now ended with .php and didn't have a trailing slash!). Try the new set of rules in my answer.